# Python how to create a new dict by add items to an old dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict:

```
d1 = {'name':'William'}
```

Now I want to build another dict that is based on d1:

```
d2 = {'name':'William','age':6}
```

Is there something like:

```
d2 = d1{'age':6}
```

Any friend can help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [unpack](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/) d1 in a dictionary display:

```
d2 = {**d1, "age": 6}
```

You can use a [dict union operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/):

```
d2 = d1 | {"age": 6}
```

You can copy and setitem:

```
d2 = d1.copy()
d2["age"] = 6
```

You can pass an existing dict along with some new keys/vals calling the `dict` builtin:

```
d2 = dict(d1, age=6)
```

Comment: Which one feels most idiomatic to you? Which one would you be most likely to use in your own code?

Comment: My preference is the first one (unpacking).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the union operator:

```
d2 = d1|{'age':6}
```